# Login works despite wrong user credentials

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase and FirebaseAuth in my Flutter app to manage users and data.

The problem is that the users are always taken to the next screen even if they enter wrong credentials. They can enter data to non-existent user accounts, or wrong passwords, and they are still taken to the text screen which should only happen after a successful auth.

As far as I understood, if code inside (if user!= null) should only be executed if the auth was successful, but it still happens all the time.

The console does log a response from Firebase, stating either a non-existent user or wrong passsword, but the code proceeds nontheless.

Does anyone see what I did wrong?
I'm still a learner, so it's probably a basic mistake :(

Thank you!!

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
...
onPressed: () async {
              try {
                final user = _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: email, password: password);
                if (user != null) {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => CoursesListScreen(),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              } catch (e) {
                print(e.message);
              }
            },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `_auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` you get back a `Future`, which will never be `nil`. So indeed the navigator will always go to the next screen. Note that the user isn't signed in at this stage, your code merely detects the wrong condition.

It's more likely that you want to wait until the `Future` resolves, which you do with `await`:

```
final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(...)
```